# How do I efficiently get a numpy array for a subset of columns from my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Motivation

I'm often answering questions in which I'm advocating converting dataframe values to an underlying numpy array for quicker calculations.  However, there are some caveats to doing this and some ways that are better than others.

I'll be providing my own answer in an effort to give back to the community.  I hope you guys find it useful.

**Problem**
Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3], B=list('xyz'), C=[9, 8, 7], D=[4, 5, 6]))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  x  9  4
1  2  y  8  5
2  3  z  7  6
```

with `dtypes`

```
print(df.dtypes)

A     int64
B    object
C     int64
D     int64
dtype: object
```

I want to create a numpy array `a` that consist of the values from columns `A` and `C`.  Assume that there could be many columns and that I'm targeting two specific columns `A` and `C`

**What I've tried**

I could do:

```
df[['A', 'C']].values

array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7]])
```

This is accurate!

However, I can do it quicker with numpy

```
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in ['A', 'C']]
df.values[:, p]

array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7]], dtype=object)
```

This is quicker, but inaccurate.  Notice the `dtype=object`.  I need integers!.

```
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in ['A', 'C']]
df.values[:, p].astype(int)

array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7]])
```

This is now correct, but I may not have known that I had all integers.

**Timing**

```
# Clear and accurate, but slower
%%timeit 
df[['A', 'C']].values
1000 loops, best of 3: 347 µs per loop

# Not accurate, but close and fast
%%timeit 
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in ['A', 'C']]
df.values[:, p]
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.2 µs per loop

# Accurate for this test case and fast, needs to be more generalized.
%%timeit 
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in ['A', 'C']]
df.values[:, p].astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` does **not** store a single array for the entire dataframe in the `values` attribute.  When you call the `values` attribute on a dataframe, it builds the array from the underlying objects that is does store, namely the `pd.Series` objects.  It's useful to think of a dataframe as a `pd.Series` of `pd.Series` where each column is one such `pd.Series` that the dataframe contains.  Each column can have a `dtype` that is different from the rest.  That is part of why dataframes are so useful.  However, a numpy array must have one type.  When we call the `values` attribute on a dataframe, it goes to each column and pulls the data from each of the respective `values` attributes and cobbles them together.  If the columns respective dtypes are inconsistent, then the `dtype` of the resulting array will be forced to be `object`.

**Option 1**
*Slow but accurate*

```
a = df[['A', 'C']].values
```

The reason this is slow is because you are asking pandas to build you a new dataframe `df[['A', 'C']]` then go and build the array `a` by hitting each of the new dataframe's columns' values attribute.

**Option 2**
*Find column positions then slice `values`*

```
c = ['A', 'C']
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in c]
a = df.values[:, p].astype(df.dtypes[c[0]])
```

This is better because we only build the values array without rebuilding a new dataframe.  I'm trusting that we are getting an array with consistent dtypes.  If up casting needs to happen, I'm not dealing with it well here.

**Option 3**
**My preferred approach**
*Only access the values of the columns I care about*

```
a = np.column_stack([df[col].values for col in ['A', 'C']])
```

This leverages the pandas dataframe as a container of `pd.Series` in which I access the `values` attribute of only the columns I care about.  I then build a new array from those arrays.  If casting needs to be addressed, numpy will handle it.

---

All approaches yield the same result

```
array([[1, 9],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 7]])
```

---

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%%timeit 
a = df[['A', 'C']].values
1000 loops, best of 3: 338 µs per loop

%%timeit 
c = ['A', 'C']
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in c]
a = df.values[:, p].astype(df.dtypes[c[0]])
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop

%timeit np.column_stack([df[col].values for col in ['A', 'C']])
The slowest run took 7.36 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.97 µs per loop
```

*big data*

```
df = pd.concat(
    [df.join(pd.DataFrame(
                np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 22)),
                columns=list(ascii_uppercase[4:])
            ))] * 10000, ignore_index=True
)


%%timeit 
a = df[['A', 'C']].values
The slowest run took 23.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 371 µs per loop
In [305]:

%%timeit 
c = ['A', 'C']
p = [df.columns.get_loc(i) for i in c]
a = df.values[:, p].astype(df.dtypes[c[0]])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.62 ms per loop

%timeit np.column_stack([df[col].values for col in ['A', 'C']])
The slowest run took 6.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Does a pd series use a numpy array to store its values?

Comment: @hpaulj I'll be honest, I can't be certain.  But I'm pretty sure it's a yes.  [**`@property; def values`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/42e2a87f2a8848795238de1259a3daa5612e393d/pandas/core/series.py#L351) refers to a `_data` attribute that I can't track down.  But the [**`def __init__`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/42e2a87f2a8848795238de1259a3daa5612e393d/pandas/core/series.py#L139) shows the `data` attribute being assigned a [**`SingleBlockManager`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/42e2a87f2a8848795238de1259a3daa5612e393d/pandas/core/internals.py#L4070)

Comment: @hpaulj and that is a numpy array... sort of :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
np.array(zip(df['A'].values, df['C'].values))
```

timeit:

```
%%timeit
np.array(zip(df['A'].values, df['C'].values))
```

The slowest run took 5.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 µs per loop